# Importing eclipse MDT/OCL APIs in qvt-o code

Tags: ocl, qvt

In a model transformation I have native OCL query as string and I need to parse that OCL string and execute it in order to identify and select specific model element in the source model.

Is it possible to import eclipse MDT/OCL API in qvt-o code? like in java

In other word , can we follow the following example but directly in qvt by importing API to qvt code without using java and black-box?

(http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.ocl.doc%2Fhelp%2FPivotEvaluatingConstraints.html&cp=38_6_5 )

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long search the answer is NO.!

We can not import OCL API in QVT-O. in such case we have to create Java code to parse the OCL and execute it and then use it in QVT-O as black-box

thanks